# Installing Python modules on Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, python, modules, python3

I have been using [Python](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29) on Windows for a while, so I'm into a lot of modules, including [Pygame](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pygame) and [LiveWires](http://tertial.livewires.org.uk/python/package?url=/python/package), but how do I install them into Ubuntu?

I have the py file for LiveWires, which has been specially edited (from a book I'm reading). I want to install it, but I'm not sure how to. I also want to install Pygame, but I can't.

Answer (score 3):

In Ubuntu, you can list the packages available with the command

```
apt-cache pkgnames
```

but its output is huge, so pipe it to grep and search for what you want, (and then pipe to sort doesn't hurt either).

```
apt-cache pkgnames | grep py | sort
```

From this, looks like you want the python-pygame package, so install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pygame
```

Answer (score 1):

Before doing anything I recommend you install virtualenv and [virtualenvwrapper](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). These make it easy to create isolated Python environments for any project you start. This comes in really handy if ever you break anything because it's isolated to one project.

Install Python modules inside a virtualenv is as easy as running:

```
pip install Pygame
```

from a terminal. `pip` will also keep track of what packages are in each of your environments, making it easy to upgrade or uninstall them when needed. Although I don't work on Windows so can't confirm, I believe this solution is also cross-platform.

Comment: I'm studying Python and Linux for the LPI cert right now.  How could you break something so bad that it affects the rest of the system, if you're just working on one python project in set directory?  When I'm on the desktop, would I be at this risk if I'm using an IDE like say, Ninja IDE?

Comment: Sorry I was unclear. There's no risk from using an IDE. The problem virtualenv solves is making sure you don't load lots of unrelated modules for different projects into the system-wide Python interpreter. Using project-specific Python interpreters means each one only ever has what it needs so you reduce the risk of a conflict.

Comment: That's very informative, thank you!  Since you mention that, I will continue to just use my IDE then, since it's more stable than gedit.  Then I don't have to worry about the modules glitch.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-pygame
```

In general, if you want some  on Linux, you search a corresponding package by

```
$ apt-cache search <python-module>
```

and install an appropriate package by apt-get install like above.